# Get node text of treeview from another application

Tags: c#, winapi, text, treeview

I've been struggling with this issue for quite a long time and I still can't find a decent documentation or example for this matter.

I'm simply trying to get the node text of a tree view located on another application using WinApi in C# and I can't find a way of doing it anywhere.

I tried exploring the TVM_GETITEM message but I couldn't get the TVITEM out of it.

How can I achieve such a thing?

Comment: are you writing the code in C#../ and if not why..? this is fairly simple to do using the native language / .net framework also if you have any existing code, please show what you have thus far

Comment: Are you interacting with a TreeView control in *your own application*, or in *a different application*? If it's the former, what's wrong with `TreeView.Node.Text`?

Comment: I've edited the content of the question. It now specifies that the treeview is on another application and I just want to get the selected node text.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into this problem myself and thought I'd share what I found.  It requires getting the IntPtr handle of the TreeView control first, so this example assumes that part is done.

```
private string getTVNodeText(IntPtr tvHandle, IntPtr nodeHandle)
{

    TVITEM tvi = new TVITEM();
    IntPtr pszText = LocalAlloc(0x40, 260);

    tvi.mask = TreeViewMsg.TVIF_TEXT;
    tvi.hItem = nodeHandle;
    tvi.cchTextMax = 260;
    tvi.pszText = Convert.ToInt32(pszText);

    SendMessageTVI(tvHandle, TreeViewMsg.TVM_GETITEM, 0, tvi);
    string nodeText = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr)tvi.pszText, 260);

    LocalFree(pszText);

    return nodeText;
}
```

Here are the PInvoke declarations you'll need:

```
[DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "SendMessageW")]
public int SendMessageTVI(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, int wParam, ref TVITEM tvi { }

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public IntPtr LocalAlloc(uint flags, uint cb) { }

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public IntPtr LocalFree(IntPtr p) { }
```

Here's the TVITEM structure

```
public struct TVITEM
{
    public int mask;
    public int hItem;
    public int state;
    public int stateMask;
    public int pszText;
    public int cchTextMax;
    public int iImage;
    public int iSelectedImage;
    public int cChildren;
    public int lParam;
    public int iIntegral;
}
```

Here are the constants for the SendMessage calls

```
[Flags()]
public enum TreeViewMsg
{
    BN_CLICKED = 0xf5,
    TV_CHECKED = 0x2000,
    TV_FIRST = 0x1100,
    TVGN_ROOT = 0x0,
    TVGN_NEXT = 0x1,
    TVGN_CHILD = 0x4,
    TVGN_FIRSTVISIBLE = 0x5,
    TVGN_NEXTVISIBLE = 0x6,
    TVGN_CARET = 0x9,
    TVM_SELECTITEM = (TV_FIRST + 11),
    TVM_GETNEXTITEM = (TV_FIRST + 10),
    TVM_GETITEM = (TV_FIRST + 12),
    TVIF_TEXT = 0x1
}
```

You can similarly look at the state of the TVITEM to determine if the node is checked.  The TV_CHECKED constant (8192) worked for me, but I'd inspect this at runtime to see what the TVITEM.state value is when it's checked.

[Here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/621199-tvm_getitem-does-not-return-unicode-label) is the link to where I found this from someone trying to get the text back in Unicode.